# How to have row lines in table span only some given percent of each column?

Tags: tables, rules

I'm trying to make a table where the row lines only span a percentage of each column (say 75% centered on the middle of the cell). In other words instead of connecting column lines like this "H" they look more like |-|. Additionally I only want some of the columns to have this and not all of them (for example columns 1 to 3 of a 4 column table. I could do this if I used FIXED width tables using \rule but it requires a width parameter and I haven't been able to figure out how to make the width adjust to whatever the width of the column ends up being.

Possible avenues might be to use \rule in a way I haven't tried. Or to modify \cline so it doesn't span the whole column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it is possible, but one would have to think about a suitable interface to set the percentage:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\cpartline#1{\@cpartline#1\@nil}
\def\@cpartline#1-#2\@nil{%
  \omit
  \@multicnt#1%
  \advance\@multispan\m@ne
  \ifnum\@multicnt=\@ne\@firstofone{&\omit}\fi
  \@multicnt#2%
  \advance\@multicnt-#1%
  \advance\@multispan\@ne
  \hfill
        \leaders\hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth\hfill
        \leaders\hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth\hfill
        \leaders\hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth\hfill
  \hfill
  \cr
  \noalign{\vskip-\arrayrulewidth}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
some longer text & an some more\\\cpartline{1-1}\cpartline{2-2}
blb & blb\\\cpartline{1-2}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tested this and it seems to work great. Unfortunately it's beyond my tex understanding to know how it's working. Quick question, should the second \makeatletter be a \makeatother? Also, if you are feeling frisky adding "left only gap" and "right only gap" commands would complete the possibilities, making your commands also useful for data spanning multiple columns, for instance.

Comment: Yes it should have been \makeatother. Also I got the math wrong. I have 5 \hfill where 3 draw a line (the leaders line) which gives 60% and not 75%. You need a relation of 2 simple \hfill and 6 "leader \hfill".

Comment: I ended up using a fixed space on each side rather than a percent (by replacing the leading and trailing \hfill with \kern4pt which means I only need one of the \leaders lines). Worked fantastic. I cannot thank you enough for your answer and am quite jealous of your tex-fu.

Comment: Can you explain how to calculate the percentages? And also how this would look like for fixed space?

Comment: @SOStinks I get `! Leaders not followed by proper glue.` when I try your suggestion. Probably I messed it up somehow. Can you maybe post your solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can leave some space before and after the column, then use a `cline{<>}` command to skip horizontal rules within the extra empty columns. To achieve the desired percentage, `(75%)` for example, you should fine tune the empty column-width, `@{ }`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|*3{c@{ }c@{ }c|} c|}\hline 
& c11 & & & c12 & & & c13 & & c14 \\ \cline{2-2}\cline{5-5}\cline{8-8}\cline{10-10} 
& c21 & & & c22 & & & c23 & & c24 \\ \cline{2-2}\cline{5-5}\cline{8-8}\cline{10-10} 
& c31 & & & c32 & & & c33 & & c34 \\ \cline{2-2}\cline{5-5}\cline{8-8}\cline{10-10} 
& c41 & & & c42 & & & c43 & & c44 \\ \hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is an interesting idea. This one would be harder to implement for my tables and since Ulrike Fischer's answer also works I accepted it, at least for now. Thank you.