# Partial cline in table only for some fraction

Tags: tables, cline, hline

Example:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
1 & 2 \\
\cline{1-1}\cline{2-2}
3 & 4 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

I want `cline` to cover only e.g. half of a cell of a table. Or maybe I can specify an offset  when the line should start (e.g. to skip the first cm).

Is this easily possible?

(One workaround could be to introduce another column, and then use `multicolumn` everywhere. But this would be somewhat annoying. Also not sure how I could control the width of the columns then. [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356667/width-of-columns-in-a-table-with-only-multicolumns) might be related.)

([This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298300/how-to-have-row-lines-in-table-span-only-some-given-percent-of-each-column) looks very related. I did not found this via Google. Maybe this can be marked as duplicate. Although the solution doesn't quite work for me (I get some errors), and I don't really understand it. I thought it is still valuable to post for other people who would use my Google search terms, to find this.)

Comment: Please provide a minimum working example.  Both because it is the protocol for this site and because it will help explain the particulars of your use case (for which alternative approaches might apply).

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, then it is duplicate to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298300/how-to-have-row-lines-in-table-span-only-some-given-percent-of-each-column?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 4):

It's easy with tikz and nicematrix.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{cc}[cell-space-top-limit=4pt]
    1 & 2 \\
    3 & 4 \\
    \CodeAfter
    \tikz\draw (3 -| 1) rectangle (1 -| 3);
    \tikz\draw (1 -| 2) -- (3 -| 2);
    \tikz\draw[red] ($(2 -| 1)!0.5!(2 -| 2)$) -- (2 -| 3);
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting. But then I need to change by `tabular` to `NiceTabular`. I don't really know this environment. I use many features of `tabular`, like siunitx, multirow, multicolumn, cline, hline. Do they all work in the same way? I would prefer to not use some completely different syntax just to have one `cline` in one place slightly different.

Answer (score 2):

I found one solution (adapted from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/298308/2272)):

```
\makeatletter
\def\cpartlineleft#1{\@cpartlineleft#1\@nil}
\def\@cpartlineleft#1,#2\@nil{%
  \omit
  \@multicnt#1%
  \advance\@multispan\m@ne
  \ifnum\@multicnt=\@ne\@firstofone{&\omit}\fi
  \@multicnt#1%
  \advance\@multicnt-#1%
  \advance\@multispan\@ne
  \kern#2
        \leaders\hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth\hfill
        \leaders\hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth\hfill
  \cr
  \noalign{\vskip-\arrayrulewidth}}
\makeatother
```

Then I can use it as:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
1 & 2 \\
\cpartlineleft{1,1em}\cline{2-2}
3 & 4 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```